# Trying to get feature importance in Random Forest(PySpark)

Tags: pyspark, random-forest, feature-selection

I have a customer data with close to 15k columns.
I'm trying to run RF on the data to reduce the number of columns and then run other ML algorithms on it.

I am able to run RF on PySpark but am unable to extract the feature importance of the variables.

Anyone having any clue about the same or any other technique which would help me in reducing the 15k variable to some 200 odd variables.